# Adding new variable using lead() and possible loop

Tags: r

I have a data-set called loc_prime2 that looks like this:

```
Document.Name   locale                  Arrival     Leg.Number  no_legs
VCH028735       DENVER_COLORADO         12/2/2018   1           2
VCH028735       _NONE                   12/7/2018   2           2
VCH028776       HARLINGEN_TEXAS         12/2/2018   1           3
VCH028776       LUBBOCK_TEXAS           12/3/2018   2           3
VCH028776       NONE                    12/4/2018   3           3
VCH030440       MEMPHIS_TENNESSEE       5/12/2019   1           6
VCH030440       NASHVILLE_TENNESSEE     5/13/2019   2           6
VCH030440       KNOXVILLE_TENNESSEE     5/14/2019   3           6
VCH030440       CHATTANOOGA_TENNESSEE   5/15/2019   4           6
VCH030440       NASHVILLE_TENNESSEE     5/16/2019   5           6
VCH030440       Kennesaw,               5/18/2019   6           6
VCH031580       EUGENE_OREGON           7/8/2019    1           8
VCH031580       NEWPORT_OREGON          7/9/2019    2           8
VCH031580       CORVALLIS_OREGON        7/10/2019   3           8
VCH031580       EUGENE_OREGON           7/11/2019   4           8
VCH031580       EUREKA_CALIFORNIA       7/12/2019   5           8
VCH031580       REDDING_CALIFORNIA      7/15/2019   6           8
VCH031580       SACRAMENTO_CALIFORNIA   7/16/2019   7           8
VCH031580       _NONE                   7/17/2019   8           8
```

I want to add a new column that holds the arrival date following the current arrival date. This needs to be done a different number of times depending on the no_legs in the trip. For instance, the first Document.Name was in Denver on 12/2; the next location associated with the Document.Name is _None meaning there was no destination after Denver. So the line for VCH028735 should be condensed to:

```
Document.Name    locale            Arrival    End        
VCH028735        DENVER_COLORADO   12/2/2018  12/7/2018
```

Note, some trips have more than 2 legs. There are trips with as many as 8 legs. For instance, VCH031580 needs to be condensed to this:

```
 Document.Name    locale                  Arrival    End        
 VCH031580        EUGENE_OREGON           7/8/2019  7/9/2019
 VCH031580        NEWPORT_OREGON          7/9/2019  7/10/2019
 VCH031580        CORVALLIS_OREGON        7/10/2019  7/11/2019
 VCH031580        EUGENE_OREGON           7/11/2019  7/12/2019
 VCH031580        EUREKA_CALIFORNIA       7/12/2019  7/15/2019
 VCH031580        REDDING_CALIFORNIA      7/15/2019  7/16/2019
 VCH031580        SACRAMENTO_CALIFORNIA   7/16/2019  7/17/2019
```

I have this for the case for when the no_legs is 2:

```
test <- as.data.frame(loc_prime2 %>% group_by(Document.Name) %>% mutate(
    end1 = as.Date(ifelse(Leg.Number == 1 & no_legs == 2, lead(Arrival), 0), 
    origin = '1970-01-01')

    # end mutate
    ) 
)
```

But to deal with the differing no_legs values, I think I'm going to need a loop or something. I'm pretty sure there's a very easy way to do what I want--I just cannot see it. Thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making it more difficult by thinking about the number of legs per group. Assuming your arrival dates are sorted in time order, all you need to do is group by`Document.Name`, then use `lead` to create the new `end` variable. You then just remove all the final rows (which will have an `NA` for `end`)

```
library(dplyr)

loc_prime2 %>% 
  group_by(Document.Name) %>% 
  mutate(End = lead(Arrival)) %>% 
  select(Document.Name, locale, Arrival, End, Leg.Number) %>%
  filter(!is.na(End))

#> # A tibble: 15 x 5
#> # Groups:   Document.Name [4]
#>    Document.Name locale                Arrival   End       Leg.Number
#>    <chr>         <chr>                 <chr>     <chr>          <int>
#>  1 VCH028735     DENVER_COLORADO       12/2/2018 12/7/2018          1
#>  2 VCH028776     HARLINGEN_TEXAS       12/2/2018 12/3/2018          1
#>  3 VCH028776     LUBBOCK_TEXAS         12/3/2018 12/4/2018          2
#>  4 VCH030440     MEMPHIS_TENNESSEE     5/12/2019 5/13/2019          1
#>  5 VCH030440     NASHVILLE_TENNESSEE   5/13/2019 5/14/2019          2
#>  6 VCH030440     KNOXVILLE_TENNESSEE   5/14/2019 5/15/2019          3
#>  7 VCH030440     CHATTANOOGA_TENNESSEE 5/15/2019 5/16/2019          4
#>  8 VCH030440     NASHVILLE_TENNESSEE   5/16/2019 5/18/2019          5
#>  9 VCH031580     EUGENE_OREGON         7/8/2019  7/9/2019           1
#> 10 VCH031580     NEWPORT_OREGON        7/9/2019  7/10/2019          2
#> 11 VCH031580     CORVALLIS_OREGON      7/10/2019 7/11/2019          3
#> 12 VCH031580     EUGENE_OREGON         7/11/2019 7/12/2019          4
#> 13 VCH031580     EUREKA_CALIFORNIA     7/12/2019 7/15/2019          5
#> 14 VCH031580     REDDING_CALIFORNIA    7/15/2019 7/16/2019          6
#> 15 VCH031580     SACRAMENTO_CALIFORNIA 7/16/2019 7/17/2019          7
```

Comment: Didn't know R would handle the differing number of legs on its own. Allan, I would tell you how long I've been working at this problem but I'm too embarrassed. Thanks for the assist.